# How to play an avi video on canvas with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, canvas

I can play a video using opencv but now i want to set it on a canvas. But when the frame i grabbed is a numpy ndarray data, then i am not able to use the func. image.resize() and create_image(). Can I transform the numpy ndarray data to an instance?  or some other ways to put the video on the canvas?

```
tkroot = Tk()
tkroot.geometry("500x500+400+100")
labelfont = ('courier', 20, 'bold')
widget = Canvas(tkroot, width=500, height=500,bg = 'white')
widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
widget.focus()
```

The play video func. is as follows:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(fileorid) 
while(video.isOpened()):
    ret,frame = video.read()
    if ret == True:
        img = frame.resize((500, 500), frame.ANTIALIAS)
        im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        widget.create_image(250,250,image = im)
        #cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        c = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if c == 32:
            c = 0
            while c!=32:
                c = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if c == 27 or ret == 0:
            break
    else:
        break
```

i also want to take a screenshot while playing. i already had a screenshot function on a canvas. that's why i want to play the video on the canvas

Comment: note that cv2.waitKey() will only work with a highgui window (imshow()), it's useless in your case.

Comment: i also want to take a screenshot while playing.  i already had a screenshot function on a canvas.

Comment: an that's why i want to play the video on a canvas